# React: FileReader onloadend doesn't recognize "this" if defined in a component method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I define a method in a React class component as follows

```
onSaveAudio = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { audioBlob } = this.state;

    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function () {
        const base64 = reader.result;
        const bstr = base64.split(',')[1];
        console.log(bstr);
        console.log('this.props', this.props);
        this.props.onSaveAudio(bstr);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(audioBlob);
    
    }
```

At the `console.log('this.props', this.props)` line, it's printing "undefined"; at the `this.props.onSaveAudio` line, an error is thrown:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onSaveAudio' of undefined at
> FileReader.reader.onloadend (recorder.js:300)

My understanding is that "onloadend" is triggered after the "reader" finishes reading "audioBlob". I need to call the `this.props.onSaveAudio` in the "onloadend" function, because if I call it outside of "onloadend", I can't time the call to after the reading finishes and "reader.result" is ready, and "bstr" would resolve to undefined with the wrong timing; but if I call the `this.props.onSaveAudio` within "onloadend", then "this" is not recognized. Seems to be a dilemma.

My guess is I need a solution to either bind "this" within "onloadend", or be able to somehow time a `this.props.onSaveAudio` call outside of the "onloadend" function, after the "onloadend" function finishes execution.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

One way I found is to use an arrow function when defining "reader.onloadend".

```
    reader.onloadend = () => {
        const base64 = reader.result;
        const bstr = base64.split(',')[1];
        console.log(bstr);
        console.log('this.props', this.props);
        this.props.onSaveAudio(bstr);
    }
```

this.props will be defined in this case